# how to call google hangout api from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello leaders can any one help me to call chat functionality from asp.net. I want to call google hangout api to communicate from one participant to another. I want to check who is online currently on hangout & want to talk with them. So how to call api from asp.net

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i am reading hangout APIs

Comment: I have https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-hangout-samples/source/browse/send-message-app/sendMessageApp.xml this XML which sends message but not getting how to use this xml in my ASP.net to send message.